# How to find out the most similar aws instance class 'c4.large' and its availability?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I tried to apply my terraform, I got this error

> - aws_instance.new_instance: Error launching source instance: Unsupported: Your requested instance type (c4.large Windows) is not
>     supported in your requested Availability Zone (us-west-2d). Please
>     retry your request by not specifying an Availability Zone or choosing
>     us-west-2a, us-west-2b, us-west-2c.

Is there any easy way to find out the next closet instance class and its availability zones?

Comment: fwiw: in AWS accounts that were created before us-west-2 had four availability zones (for many years, there were three), us-west-2d should be the label associated with the newest zone.  (Availability zone labels are randomized across accounts, so that my us-west-2a may actually be your -2b or -2c, etc., but the mapping is more deterministic when an entirely new AZ is fired up.)  As such, it would be expected for that specific zone to have the newest generations of EC2 instances, and not some of the older ones, even though they are still current generation instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you choose **Compute Optimized** instance types please check this page https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ under **Compute Optimized** section. you can calculate cost from this page https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html as your requirements. You have option to select c4.xlarge or other type depend on your future expansion plans.[image]

Comment: Can I tell this instance is available in s-west-2d too?

Comment: yes, please check https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html add choose your AZ post that select your instance type.

Answer (score 0):

There are now API calls to discover availability of Instance Types in each AZ.

See: [describe-instance-type-offerings — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-type-offerings.html)